# Is there a type of password protection that works on local files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

With my website, which is on my pc is not using localhost and I'm wondering if there are any password protection techniques that doesn't require php/htaccess or a localhost network. Just pure HTML files on my pc. I know there is no way to be fully protected since its local on my pc, but just a simple one where I can store passwords in a text file and my website uses that to get login information.

Thanks.

Comment: html files are essentially text files, and can be opened and viewed as such. So no, there's no effective password protection for a pure HTML file on your pc

Comment: Previously i was using a js login thing which the password was in the file itself. Can js get info from other files?

Comment: You really had the password harcoded in the JS file? That's a big security issue there

Comment: I used to. But that was only temporary because the website is local.

Comment: I'd like to know: why and what do you want to protect? Since your website is only local and no one from the Internet can access it, only you can have access to it

Comment: I fail to see why this has been downvoted. "How can I password-protect a html/js file in a serverless environment" is a valid and even good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, how about

```js
function gamma(text, key) {
    let res = '',
        i = 0;

    for (let c of text)
        res += String.fromCharCode(
            c.charCodeAt(0) ^ key.charCodeAt(i++ % key.length))

    return res
}

site = "Z\t\u001d\u0005\u0012O\u0011\u0004\n\u0000\u0000VA\f\u000b\n\bHL\u0003\u000fO\u0006\u0003\u0003\u001d\u0017WI\t\u001d\u0005\u0012Q"

onload = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = gamma(site, prompt('password?'))
}
```

Unless you enter a valid password (which happens to be "fork"), you'll get rubbish instead of the site.

Basically, it "encrypts" the whole web page (using a naive gamming algorithm). Since this a symmetric encryption, the same key can be used to turn the text back into the initial state.

Here's a small snippet to automate the whole thing:

```js
function gamma(text, key) {
  let res = '', i = 0;
  for (let c of text)
    res += String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) ^ key.charCodeAt(i++ % key.length))
  return res
}

$ = x => document.getElementById(x)

encode = function() {
  let site = $('site').value,
    pass = $('pass').value
  let enc = JSON.stringify(gamma(site, pass))

  $('out').value = [
    '<script>',
    `site = ${enc}`,
    gamma,
    'onload = function() {',
    'document.body.innerHTML = gamma(site, prompt("password?"))',
    '}</' + 'script>'
  ].join('\n')
}
```

```html
<h3>Ultimate web protector, patent pending!</h3>

<p><textarea id="site" cols=80 rows=10>my site</textarea></p>
<p><input id="pass" value='my password'></p>
<p><button onclick="encode()">Encode!</button></p>
<p><textarea id="out" cols=80 rows=10></textarea></p>
```

For future readers: this code is a joke, don't even think about using it to actually protect anything serious! However, if you replace the naive "encryption" above with a proven algorithm like AES, this can be used as a prototype for a real-world solution if you have a serverless environment, but still need to password-protect things.

Comment: Could you explain a bit your snippet?

Comment: Thanks! But can you please tell me how to change it from fork and to make it open a html file. If possible.

Im new sorry lol

Comment: @Amaury: updated

Comment: @Max: I've added a snippet for you to encode things. Please don't take it too seriously...

Comment: @georg Thanks heaps! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @georg Just wondering. Is there a way to remove the password part and just have it load without entering a password (While encrypted)

Comment: @Max: sure, just replace `prompt("password?")` in the above with the actual password, like `document.body.innerHTML = gamma(site, "fork")`

Comment: @georg Thanks!!